# Back reference to cell with link when using Workbook.FollowHyperlink()?

Tags: excel, vba

I create a link in a cell. The link points anywhere (e.g. "A1" in same document), because I want to do the important things in the event handler

```
Workbook.FollowHyperlink()
```

For my puporses, in FollowHyperlink() I need the link's name which is in the cell, therefore I need the back reference to the cell.

Does anyone know how? The parent object of the hyperlink is of type "range" and I guess that I do not have the information about my cell.

Comment: A *Cell* is a *Range*. e.g. *Cell A1* is `Range("A1")`. Can you please edit in a [MCVE] to demonstrate what you are trying to do?

Comment: What exactly do you mean my "*I need the link's name which is in the cell*" - is that the text displayed in the cell as the link or something else?

Comment: I think it may be anchor you're looking for

Comment: Interestingly, the "anchor" property is not supported in the hyperlink parameter given by the event handler "Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)"

Comment: @Samuel: Exactly. The text displayed in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Hyperlink.Parent.Value` ***OR*** the `Hyperlink.TextToDisplay` property.

- See the [Hyperlink.Parent property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlink.parent) documentation.
- See the [Hyperlink.TextToDisplay property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlink.texttodisplay) documentation.

Consider this example where `"ABC"` is written into Cell A1 and a hyperlink is set to cell B3. When you click the link it selects the links destination - B3 but the `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink()` event prints information to the *immediate window*.

In this instance, `Parent` is a range object (Cell A1 in the below example) that is the parent for the hyperlink.

[image: Sample data, explained above]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Debug.Print "Parent Value: " & Target.Parent.Value
    Debug.Print "Parent Absolute Address: " & Target.Parent.Address
    Debug.Print "Parent Relative Address: " & Target.Parent.Address(False, False)
    Debug.Print "Text to display: " & Target.TextToDisplay
End Sub
```

Which outputs the following to the *immediate window* when the link in A1 is clicked:

```
Parent Value: ABC
Parent Absolute Address: $A$1
Parent Relative Address: A1
Text to display: ABC
```